# Install matlab with wine

Tags: wine, matlab

I have been moving from windows to Ubuntu recently.

I have both windows 7 and matlab for windows license keys.

My question is, is it possible to use wine to install matlab(for windows)? will the performance of matlab being affected?

**Except wine, dual-boot, and purchase a new matlab for Linux license key**, what other options do I have?

Update: I just searched for virtual box, will it be a good alternative?

**Update: After trying with virtualbox, I believe it will not be a good option, because it only run with the ram allocated for it. Seems like I can only purchase a new license, if I don't want to dual-boot, which is quite not convenient**.

Comment: Just a side note: Maybe you can contact MathWorks and ask for their opinion on your situation. Matlab is already overpriced and charging loyal customers twice is not a nice move.

Comment: you will want to contact mathworks about licensing. Using MatLab in WINE or via a virtual machine would not be suggested due to MatLab's resource requirements.

Comment: @zoopster High memory and CPU requirements are not usually a reason to avoid Wine or virtualization. But are you thinking of MATLAB's ability to use the GPU for vector processing? If so, then since many games work via Wine, perhaps MATLAB's GPU computations could too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Matlab for Linux exists, the number of users who have experience with Matlab on wine is probably very limited.

If you cannot get a license that is valid on Linux, running Windows 7 (or any Windows) and Matlab with VirtualBox or KVM is certainly an option. The biggest issue is that a significant amount of RAM will be wasted for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a new licence.

At least in my case I have a licence that let's me download and install on any OS (Windows, linux or mac).

And it let's me have up to 4 simultaneous installations. So I have one running on a windows machine and one on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a linux version of matlab via the "less official" sources and then use your windows license, I'm fairly sure this will work. And since you paid for the license, I wouldn't consider this illegal.